# corner radius on a uiview not working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

```
cornerRadius = (view.frame.size.height / 2.0)
```

Doesn't seem to work as expected. How to solve this? What might be the issue?

**Output Screen-**

[image: My code and simulator output is shown in this image. Click Here]

Comment: It would help if we knew what you were expecting since it looks to be working as coded.

Comment: set the width and height constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution in this case is you should put `prepareUI` method in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Try to add the code below.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.prepareUI();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want your corner radiuses to meet each other, and not have a straight line vertically between them? So that the sides of your red and green buttons meet up in a half circle?

Your view constraints aren't actually resolved until the `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` function, so if your view changes during runtime because of the constraints you have set up, the frame you are calculating your corner radiuses from will change *after* viewDidLoad. If you use `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` instead you should be fine:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    self.prepareUI();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you only need to set clipToBounds true for your View.

Example;

> let view = UIView()
>           view.layer.cornerRadius = 14;
>           view.clipsToBounds = true;

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted, the answers are in above posts.