# Replace device orientation with interface orientation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have been using this for orientation changes

```
  if (UIDevice.current.orientation == UIDeviceOrientation.portrait)
```

How do I replace this by `UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait` in the above syntax. This is because `UIDeviceOreientation` has `faceup` and `facedown`, which are of no use to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can replace this by the below line

```
if (UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait)
```

Comment: I have an answer that says it is deprecated, so should I leave my syntax as it is without any change?

Comment: @Coder221 let try and you will know should you use it or not ;)

Comment: @Coder221 it's up on you. But let's look at your question, you ask for **How do I replace this by UIInterfaceOrientation.portrait in the above syntax** ;) and i'm sure that there won't have any problem with your application if you use my code.

Comment: yup that was my question, maybe I should ask another question regarding it.

Comment: @Coder221 Let's investigate a little before making a new question. I think you can figure out the answer by yourself ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158249/discussion-between-coder221-and-trungduc).

Comment: you mind looking at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48303609/call-viewwilltransition-in-didselectitemat-indexpath

Answer (score 2):

Trungduc's answer will work but as Apple states in [their documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinterfaceorientation):

> Starting in iOS 8, you should employ the UITraitCollection and UITraitEnvironment APIs, and size class properties as used in those APIs, instead of using UIInterfaceOrientation constants or otherwise writing your app in terms of interface orientation.

Edit: if you don't want to get into the flexibility UITraitCollection gives you you can keep your method but simplify it:

```
if (UIDevice.current.orientation.isPortrait) {
}
```

Comment: Then what would be the syntax, which is not deprecated?

Comment: @Terje you are very good guy and please don't copy another answer ;). Good luck. Hope your answer can be marked as right answer in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47119076/corner-radius-on-a-uiview-not-working-as-expected/47119191#47119191

Comment: Can you please explain flexibility of UITraitCollection in terms of my syntax

Comment: Just in terms of your syntax you have no need for UITraitCollection. Without knowing more about your app I can't really comment but there are some good blog intros to UITraitCollection out there if you Google.

I think the point Apple is trying to make is to not necessarily think just in terms of portrait and landscape now that we are starting to have many different screen sizes and devices but to rather adapt your interface on a more fine grained level.

Comment: Appreciate your explanation, will look into it.